# Skip/Remove opening Metadata in json file

Tags: json, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to use Get-IntuneManagedDevice to grab all Dell serial numbers from Intune. Right now, I'm simply trying to test getting all of the serial numbers to print. I currently have the following:

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "manufacturer eq 'Dell Inc.'" -Top 100 | ConvertTo-Json -depth 3 | Out-File -filePath ".\dellTags.json"

$test = Get-Content -Path .\dellTags.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$test | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output $_.serialNumber
}
```

However this doesn't work, due to the Metadata currently at the top of the json file. That file looks like this:

```
{
   "@odata.context": "<url>",
   "@odata.count": 100,
   "@odata.nextLink": "<url>",
   "value":  [
               {
                 <machine objects here>
               }
   ]
```

If I manually edit the json file to remove everything before the first bracket, I get the serial numbers as expected. However, seeing as this is supposed to be automated, I need a way to either remove or skip that opening metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out thanks to the following blog post:

https://powershelladministrator.com/2021/12/07/get-list-of-intune-managed-devices/

```
(Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "manufacturer eq 'Dell Inc.'" -Top 100).value
```

That skips the opening metadata.